# Error message when commissioning nodes with MAAS

Tags: maas

I have the following question:

I run an ESXi 5.5 host with an VM Ubuntu 15.10 and MAAS Version 1.8.3 (+bzr4053).

I've set everything up and start an new VM with PXE boot. It automatically handshakes with MAAS and turns off.

When i try to commission afterwards i get the following error message in MAAS:

*Failed to power on node - Node could not be powered on: virsh failed with return code 1: Failed to login to virsh console.*

I gave MAAS rights to the libvirtd group. So the permission should not be the problem.

These are the settings of the power type of my node: [Power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsPb.png)

Anyone an idea about this problem?

If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

See for more details:
https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html#virtual-machine-nodes

You need the libvirtd-bin package installed (guessing that can work with the group you've got).  See if you can run:

```
sudo virsh list --all
```

I'd guess the command is installed, your password on the VM server is incorrect.  Or the password maas uses to connect is incorrect.  SO you'd want to su to the maas user on the maas controller and run that virsh command.